# Swift SpriteKit: Game won't restart properly? Whats going?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have this game so that when my player dies I should just be able to tap the screen and the game should restart, but instead nothing moves no matter how many times I tap. There are no errors.

Here is the code for my restart function: (willing to post any other necessary code)

```
func restart() {
    cloudGenerator.stopClouds()

let newScene = GameScene(size: view!.bounds.size)
    view!.presentScene(newScene)

    newScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

}
```

Comment: Is the restart function ever called?

Comment: Yes, its called in the touchesBegan func

Answer (score 0):

So, an easy solution is to transition from your current scene to your current scene. By doing this, your code will run from the beginning of the file. You can also add fancy transitions. Here is the code:

```
let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1.0) //create a transition
let gamePlayScene = GamePlayScene(fileNamed: "GamePlayScene") // create a new scene from your file (let variableName = NameOfGameFile(fileNamed: "NameOfGameFile")
self.view?.presentScene(gamePlayScene, transition: transition) // present the scene with the transition
```

Just put this in the touches began method and have a conditional that if the clouds have been stopped and the user touches the screen, transition to current game scene.

Hope this helped and good luck.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Im still a tad confused about the first NameOfGameFile in the second line. I put that in as the name of my game, and it says "use of unresolved identifier..."

Comment: The name of the file is the name of the file that the code is located in. (the .swift file)

Comment: Alright, well the transition works fine, but my game still won't start moving

Comment: If movement starts automatically, the movement should start after the transition. If it does not, then make sure you are calling the movement functions. It will work just like you hit the run button.